# making a class of shapes that know how to draw themselves

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6

I would like to know how to get this to work.   The argument
`g` of the function `draw` is to be the graphics context of a JavaScript canvas object.

What I want is to be able to say is

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var g = c.getContext("2d");
b = new Ball(300,200, 50, "red");
b.draw(g)
```

and have a red ball paint at the center (300,200) of radius 50px.
Here is the code for the class.

```
class Ball
{
    constructor(x, y, radius, color)
    {   
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius
        this.color=color;
    }   
    draw(g)
    {   
        console.log(g.fillStyle);
        g.fillStyle = this.color;
        g.beginPath()
        //g.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        //correct is below.....
        g.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        g.fill();
    }    
}
```

Thank you for any help you can supply.  Please note I have enabled ECMA6 in my browser.  The console is not raising any error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a type-o in `draw()`. Change `this.r` to `this.radius` to match the constructed variable.

Comment: Thanks. This is one of those "dumb mistakes" I just kept not seeing.  A fresh pair of eyes is helpful and you provided it.